# Cannot pass value to page through HtmlGenericControl Property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, innerhtml, htmlgenericcontrol

Here is the .aspx file

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">            
    <input type="text" id="StringValue" runat="server"/>
    <datalist id="dataList" runat="server"></datalist>
    <% CreateContent(_sql)%>
</form>
```

And here is the .vb file (`CreateContent`)

```
Protected Sub CreateContent(ByVal sql As String)

    Dim optList As New List(Of String)
    optList = GetData(sql)

    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DataOptions"))
    For Each opt In optList
        table.Rows.Add(opt)
    Next
    For Each row In table.Rows
        dataList.InnerHtml = dataList.InnerHtml & vbCrLf & String.Format("<option value='{0}'>", row(0))
    Next
    MsgBox(dataList.InnerHtml)

End Sub
```

When I tested the page, the `MsgBox` could actually show all the `<option>` elements. However, these contents can only exist in server side. `<datalist>` is always empty in page source. Anyone can explain what prevent the content being passed to the page and how to solve it?

Comment: I don't use Web Forms myself but I don't think that you should be setting the `InnerHtml` of a `DataList`. If you were to do that, what would be the point of the control? You should be adding to the `Items` property and letting the control itself generate the appropriate HTML.

Comment: Actually, I just read the documentation for the `DataList` control and it specifically states that it's a data-bound list control, so you should be binding your data to the control and it will then expose the bound data via the `Items` collection and generate the appropriate HTML from that. It seems to me that you need to do some research on how that control works.

Comment: Actually there are some sources that suggested the way which I followed, like this: [link](https://www.encodedna.com/2014/08/bind-dynamic-data-to-html5-datalist-using-aspdotnet-datatable.htm)

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that you were using the Web Forms `DataList` control but it looks like you probably aren't. Maybe you should be but, as I said, I don't use Web Forms so there may be factors that I'm not aware of.